# Find directory path of file in php

Tags: php, search-engine

I have some doubts in creating search engine to find directory path of file.

For example, Consider this is updated code,

```
 <?php

$files = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file_to_search = $_POST['file'];
    $root_path = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\cat\\"; // your doc root

    foreach ($iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root_path, 
            RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $value) {

        if($value->getFilename() == $file_to_search) {
            $files[] = $value->getPathname();
        }   
    }
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="index1.php">
    File To Search: <input type="text" name="file" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php if(!empty($files)): ?>
<div id="output">
    <?php foreach($files as $value) {
        echo "$value<br/>";
    } ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to create search engine, which is use to find the exact directory path of certain file.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get the problem, is it anyhow connected with your code sample? Maybe try to provide expected result

Comment: No, I just run this above code, it will be display some error. I m new to php. may i know how it i spossible to creae a search engine in php? Thank you

Comment: What error message is it displaying?

Comment: No such file or directory. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to your question of getting the **exact** directory path if the certain file, alternatively, you could use a `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to search for that file that you want to know where it is inside.

Lets say, I have a structure like this:

```
/var/
  /www/
      /test/
         /images/
             /images1/
                 image.png <--- this one for example
                 image.jpg
             /images2/
                 image3.png
```

Lets say you want to search *image.png*. Consider this example:

```
$file_to_search = 'image.png';
$root_path = '/var/www/test'; // your doc root

foreach ($iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root_path, 
        RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $value) {

    if($value->getFilename() == $file_to_search) {
        echo $value->getPathname();
    }   
}

// should output: /var/www/test/images/images1/image.png
```

Simple Application of the code above:

```
<?php

$files = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file_to_search = $_POST['file'];
    $root_path = '/var/www/test'; // your doc root

    foreach ($iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root_path, 
            RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $value) {

        if($value->getFilename() == $file_to_search) {
            $files[] = $value->getPathname();
        }   
    }
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    File To Search: <input type="text" name="file" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php if(!empty($files)): ?>
<div id="output">
    <?php foreach($files as $value) {
        echo "$value<br/>";
    } ?>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) echo 'no file found'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `glob()` function, to search for files

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use this 2 built-in function

#### Name of Current Directory

```
echo basename(__DIR__);
```

#### Name of the Current File

```
echo basename(__FILE__);
```

And **FILE** to get current file path

```
// Current file fullpaths
$current_file = str_replace('\\','/',__FILE__);
```